# Subversion repository type

Tags: svn, repository, berkeley-db, fsfs

How can I tell if a respository uses BerkeleyDB or FSFS?

Answer (score 4):

look into `db/fs-type` file in your repository (that is, of course, accessing it directly).

Answer (score 1):

Crack open the "fs-type" file in your Subversion repository; e.g. `D:\Development\SVN\db\fs-type`. Mine shows "fsfs". It will show "bdb" for BerkeleyDB.